# Is it possible to make an app like this with Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, chat, whatsapp

I want to exercise myself making an app like Whatsapp but a bit different. I don't have a lot of experience in mobile apps programming but I can learn. I've found Apache Cordova on the net I think it could be a good way to start. As I said before I want to do something like whatsapp also using a geolocalization service based on Google maps API V3. what I want to ask is: is it possible to do it with Cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Since it is HTML/JS based you can easily integrate the Google Maps v3 API.

Geolocation is possible using this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md .

And for push notifications you can use: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin